# How to strip multiple spaces, newline and tabs and just put single space in a text file?

Tags: python, parsing, formatting, text-parsing

I have shakespeare's full works data from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiltOu_wa7WAhUKN48KHVyWDIAQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fans7870%2F6%2F6.006%2Fs08%2Flecturenotes%2Ffiles%2Ft8.shakespeare.txt&usg=AFQjCNEfRTHs2tqc-_fknloRt_HT-wC1ag) that I want to use in a word embedding algorithm to create a model. The model's requirement is that the whole text be provided with only single spaces present and no other kind of whitespaces be present. How can I perform this? I found how to do this for a single string but it isn't working for a text file.

My try(I am not very knowledgeable of python):

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        cleanedline = line.strip('\n')
```

The cleanedline doesnt have the `\n` removed when printed, so I didn't write them back into file.

Comment: so, all newlines and other whitespaces should be replaces with a single space?

Comment: Yes, its [glove](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/README.md) model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a regular expression:

```
import re

with open(file_path) as data:
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', data.read())
```

The `\s+` regular expression pattern will match any sequence of one or more whitespace characters. [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will substitute the matching text for a single space.

Whitespace consists of characters such as space, tab, new line, return, form feed, vertical tab etc. It does not include punctuation.

Another way to do this without regex is to use `split()` then `join()`:

```
with open(file_path) as data:
    text = ' '.join(data.read().split())
```

Comment: @leehuang: it worked for me. What is the error that you see, or what didn't work?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, I was doing some mistake in my own code.